# OneNote online and Android Equations

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010, equation-editor

I need to take notes that include math equations. The equation editor in the desktop version of OneNote is great and does an fantastic job. However, i need to be able to see these equations in other media, such as OneNote online or on my Android device. I am cool with not creating the equations there, but I need to be able to at least see them.

Is that simply a missing feature that I will not solve without Microsoft adding a feature? Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to handle this?

If it makes a difference I am using OneNote 2010.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature request [thread](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327165-onenote-for-mac/suggestions/6428439-add-support-for-equations-in-onenote-mac-and-oneno). for this, so no, I don't believe it is possible without Microsoft updating the application on their side.

There are workarounds for this however.

- Save your notes as an application-agnostic format such as PDF that will preserve the text and equation across devices.
- Use LaTeX for your formulas in export them to OneNote as highlighted by this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13217).

Answer (score 0):

The only way as of now is to add a screen shot alongside of the equation

Comment: It actually kinda does answer the question. For older versions of OneNote, the mobile app does not support all the same content of the desktop program, including equations. I don't know if this has changed recently, but it was true not more than a few months ago when last I read the changelog on the OneNote app update.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, OneNote has the ability to show equations in android version.